# Pencil Evos tool - limitations

Tags: wireframe

does anyone have experience using Pencil Evos tool for App Wire Framing?

It seems to be great and I have seen that has many interesting features but I was wondering if in your experience there are any limitation (e.g. export format issues, lack of community suppurt).

http://pencil.evolus.vn/

I do not want this quetion to be **opinion based** but solely **fact based**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using it for the first time today, from what I've gathered it is useful for quickly mocking up a design to send to a client so you can change it based on their feedback. It's pretty simple to use, and is fine for testing just the layout and which pages link to others (although I'm having trouble with the link to tool).

One limitation I have found is that you can't switch pages between projects without having to edit the file in notepad and copying the content between the  tags over to another file, or switching them around to change the ordering of pages.

Comment: No worries. About that page switching thing, when I tried to do it it introduced a bug which wouldn't let me create links between the pages, but if you duplicate the page you've copied in and delete the original you copied over, then you can link between the pages as if they've been created in the same project